# HDFS BLOCK SIZE

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

What is default block size 128MB or 64MB for hdfs?In hadoop definite guide it is mentioned as "HDFS, too, has the concept of a block, but it is a much larger unit—128 MB by default".Anyone can tell which is the default size?

Answer (score 3):

The best place to refer the default values of hadoop configuration is the apache hadoop [website](http://hadoop.apache.org). The default configurations and values are present in the default xml files in apache hadoop website.

The answer to your question is present in the [hdfs-default.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.9.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml). The latest stable version of hadoop as of now is 2.9.0 and the value of block size (`dfs.blocksize`) is 128 MB (`134217728 bytes`).

In hadoop 1.x the default value of block size was 64 MB. Now in the world with high speed network and low cost storage, they made the default value as 128 MB.

***Note:*** The `hdfs-default.xml`, `core-default.xml`, `yarn-default.xml` files present in the apache website can be used as the reference to find the default values of properties in apache hadoop.

Answer (score 1):

This [document](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml) states that it is `128M` (search for `dfs.blocksize`)